# jQuery can't get if statement to work

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm looking help with an If Statement. I'm trying to finalize this horizontal scrolling I have and the last bit is to not just disable scrolling when the end is reached, but to also disable (well, change color) the scroll buttons at that point as well. And change back when they are scrollable again.

http://jsfiddle.net/stfzy/83/

EDIT* I've updated the JQuery and have everything working except just one if statement:

```
$('div#arrowL').click(function(){
    if(index < 0 ){ //can't scroll
        $('div#arrowL').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

I need to add this class back when you can't scroll left anymore. And I think the issue is with the "index < 0" portion but I don't see what I need to change it to to get it to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear what your specific problem is.  Describe the steps to reproduce the issue, describe what happens and describe what you want to happen.  Two of your `if` statements (the ones outside the `.click()` handlers will only be executed once when the page first loads.

Comment: Thank you for that comment. It opened my eyes to the solution. I got the statement to work with the right side arrow/button now. Just don't know where I'm going wrong on the left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `if(index...` statements will only run when page loads. They need to be in your click handlers in order to check current state. Since you already have the reverse test, simply add an `else`

```
$('div#arrowR').click(function() {
    if (index < endIndex) {
        index++;
        $item.animate({
            'left': '-=300px'
        });
        $('div#arrowR').removeClass('active');
    }else{       
        $('div#arrowR').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/stfzy/48/

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm looking for it to work a bit differently (look at my updated jsfiddle, it works for right side how I want it), but you definitely helped guide me to the right approach.

Comment: I looked... the way you are writing it in 3 click handlers for each element is very bad practice and will lead to code that is hard to maintain or extend